# Logarith at base 10 as integration

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The logarithmic function with base $e$ is the (set theoretic) inverse of exponential function $e\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$. This can also be defined using integration as: $\log\colon (0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\log x= \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$.

**Question:**  Can we define logarithm at base $10$ using integration?

Comment: I think $\log_{10} x=\dfrac{\log_e x}{\log_e 10}$ is already a nice definition.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm of base then can be integrated but the base has to be changed to $e$.
When you have a function, lets say $f(x)=logx$ then the base can be changed from 10 to $e$. This is done using the rule $log_mx=(log_nx)/(log_nm)$.
So changing from base 10 to base *e* would look as follows:
$log_{10}x=(log_ex)/(log_e10)$.

Comment: I didn't understand the point. Can you explain it further?